# Making table from JSON file

Tags: html, angularjs, json, xml, xmltable

I have XML file with structure like

```
<theme1>
  <id>
  <name>
  <students>
    <stu1>
      <max>
      <count>
    </stu1>
    <stu2>
      <max>
      <count>
    </stu2>
  </students>
<theme1>
<theme2>
  <id>
  <name>
  <students>
    <stu1>
      <max>
      <count>
    </stu1>
    <stu2>
      <max>
      <count>
    </stu2>
  </students>
<theme2>
```

---

Can I somehow create a table like this using angularjs:
https://jsfiddle.net/xc8bufns/

Here is the sample:

> [{"ThemeName":"Theme1","TestId":52,"visible":true,"students"‌​:[{"Test_id":52,"FIO‌​":"Name1","max":4,"c‌​ount":4},{"Test_id":‌​52,"FIO":"Name2","ma‌​x":5,"count":1},]},{‌​"ThemeName":"Theme2"‌​,"TestId":85,"visibl‌​e":true,"students":[‌​{"Test_id":0,"FIO":"‌​Name1","max":0,"coun‌​t":0},{"Test_id":0,"‌​FIO":"Name2","max":0‌​,"count":0}]}}]

Comment: This is not JSON structure, this looks like XML

Comment: add original data from your json file, or data network

Comment: [{"ThemeName":"Theme1","TestId":52,"visible":true,"students":[{"Test_id":52,"FIO":"Name1","max":4,"count":4},{"Test_id":52,"FIO":"Name2","max":5,"count":1},]},{"ThemeName":"Theme2","TestId":85,"visible":true,"students":[{"Test_id":0,"FIO":"Name1","max":0,"count":0},{"Test_id":0,"FIO":"Name2","max":0,"count":0}]}}]

Here is the sample